# Migration from Innodb to NDB hurdles and issues?

Tags: mysql, database, scalability, innodb, cluster-computing

I have a highly normalized & indexed innodb database (search managed with an external sphinx server) that I am considering moving to NDB to handle a possible soon-coming mega-influx in traffic.

To the best of my research and understanding, this isn't an overly difficult maneuver as I have no fulltext fields (varchar(256) at worst) and searching is handled externally anyways.

I do realize that my join queries will degrade quite a bit, however i'm dealing with that by caching most queries with memcached (also external).

Is there anything else I should be aware of when considering this migration? The get-up-and-go document provided at http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/get-started.html#quickstart make the setup for linux seem pretty easy, although I'm not 100% on the best way to do backups and adding new nodes yet (assuming that I'll just do EBS snapshots via AWS, the system is running on EC2 Currently).

Any wisdom from the gods of ndb?

Comment: No foreign key support in NDB currently, which may or may not be critical for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would be worth checking out the functional differences between MySQL Cluster (NDB) and InnoDB, see the docs here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-compared.html

Also, the deployment best practices webinar includes a section on migrating from innodb to Cluster (note: registration required):
http://mysql.com/news-and-events/on-demand-webinars/display-od-559.html

Any questions, please post to the cluster forum forums.mysql.com/list.php?25